# Изменение переменной полученной от MySQL

Tags: javascript, php

Перерыл почти все существующие форумы, никак не могу понять как можно сделать так, что бы переменная полученная путём mysql запроса изменялась в реальном времени на PHP странице без перезагрузки, то есть идея такая, когда сканируешь QR-код, автоматом происходит подтверждение и тебя должно редиректить с той страницы, откуда был отправлено подтверждение, думаю реализовать так:

В какой-то цикл сделать проверку на изменяющуюся проверку подтверждения и всё.

Comment: Ой, жесть... Тебе нужен ajax. Пожалуй, этой подсказкой и ограничусь.

Comment: Обычным PHP не отделаюсь?))

Comment: Ну ты ж без перезагрузки хочешь.

Comment: PHP работает **на сервере**

Comment: Понял, спасибо)

Comment: Для начала сделай просто обновление данных, без БД.

Comment: Да БД и функционал есть, всё готово, нужна динамическая проверка подтверждения, или 0 или 1, она тоже есть, только нужно постоянно обновлять запрос, т.к. не известно за какое время произойдет активация.

Comment: Вот что вам нужно https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-longpoll Суть проста отправляем ajax запрос, ждем ответ, если в течении секунд 20-30 его не поступило, то сбрасываем соединение и открываем его заново, и так пока не будет получен ответ.